# HTML code for bold arrow symbol

Tags: html, dom

I searched internet the maximum I can. But couldn't find the HTML code for the symbol attached below:

[image]

I need to use this in a anchor tag.

Comment: [Unicode Character 'BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE' (U+25B6)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b6/index.htm) (after 30 secs of googling)

Answer (score 4):

```
&#9654;
```

▶

(stackoverflow has post minimum length, this is filler)

Answer (score 1):

Filled triangle pointing right

▶

```
&#9654;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [font-face](http://www.w3cplus.com/blog/tags/26.html), for example [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/app/) tool online, it is very easy to help you create the icon.